# Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `PowerPoint.Application': Invalid syntax

Tags: php, jpeg, powerpoint

When I run this below code on live server. It gives me error:

```
$ppApp = new COM("PowerPoint.Application");
$strPath = realpath(basename(getenv($_SERVER["SCRIPT_NAME"]))); 
$path = get_template_directory_uri();
$ppName = $path."/upload/".$fileName1;  
$FileName = $path."/upload/images";
$ppApp->Presentations->Open(realpath($ppName));
$ppApp->ActivePresentation->SaveAs(realpath($FileName),17); //'*** 17=JPG, 18=PNG, 19=BMP ***'
$ppApp->Quit;
$ppApp = null;
```

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message 'Failed to create COM object `PowerPoint.Application': Invalid syntax

This code work well on local server. But not run on live server.
I have been appreciated to send me any suggestions or solution related to this problem.

Comment: what is exact error ? like this : Failed to create COM object `PowerPoint.Application': The server process could not be started because the configured identity is incorrect. Check the username and password.